# Mac OS X 10.7.5 file copying, deleting takes a long time

Tags: macos, filesystems

When I try to copy/move/delete a file, even a very small file, it'll sometimes take 5 seconds.
I'm wondering what the cause of the delay is and how I can fix it.

Gracias!

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!
Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!
Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!

Comment: I'll have to check next time it happens, but a restart does fix the issue.

Comment: Sounds good. Any time you're trying to figure out what's going on behind the scenes on a system, it's always good to look at the various logs the system is already generating, to see if they provide any clues. OS X makes this easy with Console.app, especially the sidebar that helps you find all the different logs the system generates.

Answer (score -1):

What are you at in terms of hard drive space? I've noticed that starts to happen to me when I'm approaching 75-80% full because it's running out of space for reindexing and other background processes.

---

It may be just time to clear the table. For optimization purposes on macs, hard drives don't "erase" things when they are deleted, they continue down the line and go back to those empty spaces when that room is needed. As for your situation, you can think of it as the hard drive has technically filled itself and is now going back over its entire length to find the blank areas to fill in with the room it needs. This applies to deleting as well because say a movie file could be spread across 7 locations on the hard drive at this point and deleting it would require visiting all 7 of those locations in order to do the job.

If I were you I would:

1. Partition the free space on your hard drive and leave only around 10GB of extra room in your currently full partition. Make sure the new one is formatted as free space or encrypted because that will force every bit to be rewritten. (This will take a while and I wouldn't recommend you be doing anything while its doing this since its being left so little room to work with during the process).
2. Delete the newly created partition and re-expand the partition you are using.

That will make the remainder of the mac fresh and never been touched before and should help a lot with the hard drive performance.

Comment: Using only a little more than 50%